# Screenshot of UIAlertView

Tags: ios, rendering, uialertview

I need to get a screenshot of my app when there is a `UIAlertView` present.
In iOS7 I use

```
[[self getMainWindow] drawViewHierarchyInRect:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] afterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

The problem is that the image turns to be with awkward colours and strange behaviour. The image I get is bad - Following is my image.

[image]

I've tried many different things without any success of getting the colours and image right.

In iOS6 I haven't find a way to capture the `UIAlertView` at all. What is the best way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Actually the problem is related to `renderInContext` prior to `drawViewHierarchyInRect`.
If I remove it, the image is of the alert view itself, without the view beneath it. If I keep the render prior to it, the image is the result. Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is the link to the image - http://i.imgur.com/kMJ6CaK.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it happen by capturing the `UIAlertView` window itself. 
Iv'e neglected `drawViewHierarchyInRect` in favour of `renderInContext` and also rendering the `UIAlertView` window in a different method:

```
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
// Center the context around the window's anchor point
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [alertView center].x, [alertView center].y);
// Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [alertView transform]);

// Y-offset for the status bar (if it's showing)
NSInteger yOffset = 0;
if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden && !isIOS7)
    yOffset = -20;

// Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
 CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                  -[alertView bounds].size.width * [[alertView layer] anchorPoint].x,
                  -[alertView bounds].size.height * [[alertView layer] anchorPoint].y + yOffset);

// Restore the context
[[alertView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

I got the correct window by registering to `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and according to the window prefix getting the alert window - differs between `IOS6` and `IOS7`.

Another important issue was the main window. Apparently, in `IOS7` when a `UIAlertView` is shown, it becomes the main window so when trying to render the main window you only get the alert view without the views beneath it. So, to get the correct main window I've modified my getMainWindow method to comply with this scenario:

```
- (UIWindow *)getMainWindow
{
    UIWindow *topWndow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *topController = topWndow.rootViewController;

    if (topController == nil || [[topWndow description] hasPrefix:@"<_UIModalItemHostingWin"])
    {
        // The windows in the array are ordered from back to front by window level; thus,
        // the last window in the array is on top of all other app windows.
        for (UIWindow *aWndow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows reverseObjectEnumerator])
        {
            if (![[aWndow description] hasPrefix:@"<_UIModalItemHostingWin"])
            {
                topController = aWndow.rootViewController;
                if (topController)
                    return aWndow;
            }
        }
    }

    return topWndow;
}
```

Now I have a proper screenshot with alert view both for ios6/7

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to capture UIAlertview and Keyboards in the screen shot.

I have created a function that will help capturing screenshot of all the elements of a window.

here it is!

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot
{
    UIWindow *win = appDelegate.window;

    // Also checking for version directly for 3.2(.x) since UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions appears to exist
    // but can't be used.
    float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    if (systemVersion >= 4.0f)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(win.frame.size, NO, 0);

    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(win.frame.size);
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    //NSInteger count = 0;

    NSMutableArray *arrAllWindow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrAllWindow addObjectsFromArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]]; // This will allow keyboard capturing

    //below code will allow UIAlertview capturing
    if (IS_Ios8)
    {
        if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow description] hasPrefix:@"<_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWin"])
        {
            [arrAllWindow addObject:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow description] hasPrefix:@"<_UIModalItemHostingWin"])
        {
            [arrAllWindow addObject:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<arrAllWindow.count; i++)
    {
        UIWindow *window = [arrAllWindow objectAtIndex:i];
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);

        // Y-offset for the status bar (if it's showing)
        NSInteger yOffset = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden ? 0 : -20;

        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y + yOffset);

        [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:win.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: To capture UIAlertview, call above method in **-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView** But if you are not alertview delegate then call it with some delay after **[alertview show]** method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want an image or a snapshot view, but if the latter, taking a snapshot of the screen worked to get the alert view and the background. As a test, after creating the snapshot, I dismissed the alert and added the snapshot view as a subview, and the switch from the "live" alert to the snapshot view was seamless.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIAlertView *alert;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *aView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)showAlert:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"This is my message to test the alert view" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [self.alert show];
}


-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    self.aView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
    [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.aView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't use your code as I'm not the alert view's delegate.

Comment: @Adam, you don't need to be the delegate, you could call the code I have in didPresentAlertView any way you want, as long as you call it with a slight delay to make sure the alert is showing before you try to render it.

Comment: It is written in the docs that "Sent to the delegate after an alert view is presented to the user." - You say that whenever I call this function I will get the alertView that is currently showing?

Comment: @Adam, I don't understand your comment. Call what function? In my last comment, I'm saying that you can put the code I have in didPresentAlertView, into a different method that you call with a delay inside showAlert: (in my example) . Inside that method self.alert will be the alert you created and in showAlert.

Comment: now I understand your comment but it won't help me as it is not me showing the alert. I don't know when it is shown and I needed to get its screen. I've actually figured it out and added an answer here.